# How to make corner round and center align text in frame option pysimlegui python

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want to convert corner to round as well as move text to center. I am currently using PysimpleGUI to make an app[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS8W3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible right now to round corner in pysimplegui. but you can set title in center using `title_location='n'.`

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
layout1 = [[sg.Text('temp text : ',pad=(3,3)),sg.Input('input field inside frame')]]

layout = [
          [sg.Frame('title',layout=layout1,title_location='n',)]
         ]

window = sg.Window('frame ', layout,)

event, values = window.read()

window.close()
```